# With LINQ, why does a GroupBy when there's only one record not return any rows?

Tags: c#, linq

t1 contains just one row:

```
var t2 = t1
   .GroupBy(x => x.DateYYMMDD)
   .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
   .Select(g => new ScreenTimeModel
   {
      DateYYMMDD = $"20{g.Key.Substring(0, 2)}/{g.Key.Substring(2, 2)}/{g.Key.Substring(4, 2)}",
      LearnTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(g.Where(gx => gx.Mode == (int)MO.Learn).Sum(gi => gi.ScreenSeconds)).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"),
   });
```

When I try to run this code and check t2 I find that there are no elements.

Should there not be the one element at least?

Comment: Please, share the example data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure but i think this is because your t2 variable is in a state request so you should try to call ToList() method after the .Select call and reverify.

Comment: Will try that now